# Hide table row if data doesn't exist

Tags: php, wordpress

I'll like to know if there is a code I could use to prevent table rows from forming if there is no data in the custom fields.

For example this is my table:

```
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $place_1; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $person_1; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $status_1; ?></td>
            <td><a href="<?php echo $website_1; ?>"></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $place_2; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $person_2; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $status_2; ?></td>
            <td><a href="<?php echo $website_2; ?>"></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $place_3; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $person_3; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $status_3; ?></td>
            <td><a href="<?php echo $website_3; ?>"></a></td>
        </tr>
```

How can I make it that "if $place_2 is empty, hide all the table rows of 2 and 3?"

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply use PHP to only output the row when it is not empty:

```
...
</tr>
<?php if ($place_2 != "") { ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $place_2; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $person_2; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $status_2; ?></td>
    <td><a href="<?php echo $website_2; ?>"></a></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
<tr>
...
```

This approach wraps the `tr` element in an `if` block. There are other many ways to achieve the same result, which may show up in other answers. Based on your question, it looks like you want to suppress `$place_3` as well when `$place_2` is empty. I assume `$place_3` would be empty in this case, so you could apply the same approach to that `tr` element, substituting `$place_2` with `$place_3`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a WHILE loop also . This will work for any number of rows. Simply replace 4 with number of rows to be checked in `While` condition

```
<?php
 $i=0;
 while($i<4)
 {
   if($place_.$i == "")
      break; // if $place_ variable is empty no further rows are printed.
   else
   {
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $place_.$i; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $person_.$i; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $status_.$i; ?></td>
        <td><a href="<?php echo $website_.$i; ?>"></a></td>
    </tr> 
<?php
   } // closing bracket of else
  $i = $i + 1;
 } //end of while loop
?>
```